# Check offsetTop of div dynamically on div scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, offset, addeventlistener

I'm trying to alert message when uswr scroll 50px in div but it doesn't work:

```
function handleScroll() {
  console.log('scrolling... ', this.offsetTop);
  if(this.offsetTop > 50) alert('scrolled more than 50px!');
}
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

What's going on? [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VGqrdQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function handleScroll() {
 alert('scrolling... '+ this.scrollTop);
  if(this.scrollTop > 50) alert('scrolled more than 50px!');
 }
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

Comment: offset top just tell the co-ordinate of element vertically but scroll top tells the exact amount scrolled. up vote if  you get this..